# XSLT lower-case using .NET

Tags: c#, xslt

i use the following XSLT by using XMLSpy:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" indent="yes"/>
        <xsl:template match="*">
        <xsl:element name="{lower-case(local-name())}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="* | text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="@*">
        <xsl:attribute name="{lower-case(local-name())}"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If i try to use it in my source (XslCompiledTransform) i get an exception telling me that the function 'lower-case()' is not part of the XSLT synthax.

So i changed the transformation a little bit:

```
fn:lower-case
```

Now my exception is that the script or external object prefixed by 'http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions' can not be found.
Whats the matter here? How can i fix it?

Regards

Comment: Can you post the code you are transforming with? Are you creating a NameTable and populating it with the correct namespaces?

Comment: @Jaster: This is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet. I think XMLSpy use Altova XSLT 2.0 processor, wich is fine. But then you mention XslCompiledTrandform... Are you running this transformation in "plain" .NET? This has an XSLT 1.0 processor.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete XSLT1.0/XPath1.0 solution. :)

Comment: @Alejandro is there any class within "plain" .NET (up to Version 4) to use XSLT 2.0? I am not really willing to use 3rd party stuff for this ;)

Comment: @Jaster: I'm sorry, but the answer is no... You can use @Dimitre's answer, with the proper modifications in case localization is needed.

Comment: Well Dimitre's solutions works for me. I have pretty straight forward objects with no language specific characters. What i don't get is the "why" of the leak of XSLT 2 in .NET. I mean they do Threading stuff like every version. While XML, as a deep part of .NET is barley changed... Facing the fact that XSLT 2.0 exists since about 2007 and haven't found its way to the framework in 2010 is kinda ridiculous.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**.NET does not implement XSLT 2.0/XPath 2.0.**

In XPath 1.0 one can use the following expression, instead of `lower-case()`:

```
translate(yourString, 
          'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 
          'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
```