# Using XSLT lower-case function

Tags: c#, xpath, asp.net-4.0

I am using .net 4.0

How can I rewrite following xpath, to be valid

```
//Menu[fn:lower-case(./Link) = 'xyxysyx']
```

I am getting this error:

> Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

I dont know how to resolve this problem with **XmlNamespaceManager** which namespace I need to add...

if I do it like this it works:

```
 //Menu[./Link = 'xyxysyx']
```

but I need it to be lower case compare.

and here is the context where this is combined:

```
 IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement> menus = xml.Root.XPathSelectElements(xpath, namespaceManager);
```

note that we can pass to XPathSelectElements secon argument which is XmlNamespaceManager

**Edit**
Here is working example with translate function:

```
//Menu[translate(./Link, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz') = 'yz']
```

Comment: Did you try like this `//Menu[lower-case(./Link) = 'xyxysyx']`. Also in your code, the closing square bracket is missing

Comment: Sadly, you can't thanks to Microsoft not really advancing support for XSLT. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4125130/namespaces-for-xslt-using-net for the alternative (which is also why I've voted to close).

Comment: I forgot here to write it but it exist, now I will edit post

Comment: The translate syntax (after your edit) seems correct. What does not work?

Comment: sorry, yes it is working, my mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`lower-case()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-lower-case) is a standard XPath 2.0 function and is implemented only in XSLT 2.0 processors**.

To run your code "as-is" you need an XSLT 2.0 processor. There are two well-known XSLT 2.0 processors developed for use in .NET:

1. [Saxon 9.x for .NET](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/) (Saxon.NET)
2. [XQSharp](http://www.xmlprime.com/xmlprime/index.htm)

**Do note**:

The namespace prefix can be omitted from names of standard XPath 2.0 functions because the XSLT processor uses a correct default namespace for all unprefixed function names.

Therefore, just write:

```
lower-case(./Link)
```

instead of:

```
fn:lower-case(./Link)
```